# Problems with creating new environment with Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, virtual-environment

I was having problems with Anaconda, so I decided to uninstall and re-install it. No problems untill here. I wanted to recreate my env with the packages that i need to use for a project. So I broswered in the Anaconda Navigator for the section Environments > Create and this occurs:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package vc conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> vc[version='14.*|>=14,=14.1,Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip
Package sqlite conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> sqlite[version='>=3.26.0,=3.28.0,=3.30.1,Package openssl conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,
```

What can I do? I'm not so good at resolve these kinds of problems.

To say something more: when I clicked on the Create button, it popped up a window where you have to choose a environment name and the python version; from the list of the possible versions I choosed Python 3.7, maybe this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try working in the terminal.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html Here's the documentation on how to create, delete the environment and so on. After you create one try installing the libraries not with pip but with conda. Just google "conda + library u want to install" and find the code on anaconda.org website. For example, if you google conda numpy https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numpy this one will pop up.

The other thing is that some libraries dont want to work with each other. Although in my experience you still should be able to install them. The problem would be just the fact that one will try to downgrade the parts of the other. So please write which packages were you trying to install

Comment: Succesfully created a new env from terminal with 'conda create --name easy'. But when I run 'conda install numpy scipy matplotlib sympy' other errors come out, how can I share these errors to you?

Comment: You have to install these packages seperately. So for example, https://anaconda.org/anaconda/scipy here it says that the code  conda install -c anaconda scipy will install the scipy library. You have to do the same for each of them. Google conda install "name of the package you want to install". Also it's better if you add the python version when creating the environment like this conda create -n myenv python=3.7. It will save you from some troubles

Comment: When months ago I created my first custom env with conda (via terminal) it was easier. All what I had to do was 'conda create...' and 'conda install package_name' and nothing else to be specified in the command options

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple, you are installing packages with version incompatibility, if you install like this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge something
```

do it by indicating the version

```
conda install -c conda-forge something=1.1.1
```

Regarding openssl, I recommend you to use version 1.0.2, the ones after that always bring problems (for now).

```
conda install -c conda-forge something=1.0.2
```